# How to interpret a string as a multiline cell of expressions

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation

I need a string like the following:

```
"2+2
\"Hello
world\"
3+3"
```

to be evaluate like

```
2+2
"Hello 
world"
3+3
```

Note that `ToExpression` evaluates that string as

```
2+2;
"Hello 
world";
3+3
```

that is that it prints only the last line.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following code

```
str = "2+2
\"Hello
world\"
3+3";
ToExpression[str, InputForm, Print /@ List[##] &];
```

does what you want. Alternatively, you can use

```
ToExpression[str, InputForm, List]
```

and decide what to do with the list later. The documentation for `ToExpression`
states:

> `ToExpression`[*input*, *form*, *h*]
>
> wraps the head *h* around the expression produced before evaluating it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I came to a similar solution: `Print/@(List@@ToExpression[s, Inputform, Hold])`. So,  in general terms, how would you explain the role of the third argument of `ToExpression` ? and what is the default function `ToExpression` calls if the third argument is omitted?